# Android Camera two preview from single camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to build application android about camera two preview from a single camera [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQHtb.png)

I tried build app,I using SurfaceView in Android Studio but I have problem, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkROB.png)

I want example code, Can you help me please?
Thank you so much.

---

I tried app.

AndroidSurfaceviewExample.java

```html
package th.in.cybernoi.cardboardview;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AndroidSurfaceviewExample extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {
    TextView testView;

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000).show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }



    //Surfacrview
    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        //take the picture
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        refreshCamera();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // open the camera
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();

        // modify parameter
        param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
            // the preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // stop preview and release camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="th.in.cybernoi.cardboardview.MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Update Edit code Now :9/02/16

1. edit to AndroidSurfaceviewExample.java

   - add public void onPreviewFrame()

```html
    public class AndroidSurfaceviewExample extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView testView;

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceHolder camera01;
    SurfaceHolder camera02;

    SurfaceView surfaceViewLeft;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolderLeft;

    SurfaceView surfaceViewRight;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolderRight;

    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceViewLeft = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewLeft);
        surfaceHolderLeft = surfaceViewLeft.getHolder();

        surfaceViewRight = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewRight);
        surfaceHolderRight = surfaceViewRight.getHolder();

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        surfaceHolderLeft.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolderRight.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolderLeft.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        surfaceHolderRight.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        /*
        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000).show();
                refreshCamera();
            }


        };
        */
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    //Surfacrview


    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolderLeft.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolderLeft);
            camera.startPreview();


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }



    public void onPreviewFrame() {

        if (surfaceHolderRight.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }


        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            surfaceHolderLeft.lockCanvas();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolderRight);
            camera.setPreviewCallback((Camera.PreviewCallback) surfaceHolderLeft);
            camera.startPreview();


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        refreshCamera();
        onPreviewFrame();
        
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // open the camera
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();

        // modify parameter
        param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
            // the preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolderLeft);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // stop preview and release camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "AndroidSurfaceviewExample Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://th.in.cybernoi.cardboardview/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "AndroidSurfaceviewExample Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://th.in.cybernoi.cardboardview/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/

Comment: Thank you for help me : ) , I tried so but I don't know about to second view in single camera. Can you help me please.

Comment: what, exactly, is the problem that you are experiencing?  You say "failed", but what does that mean?  does your program crash?  Does one image work, and the other not?  Is the second view supposed to be somehow different than the first, or is it just a duplicate image on the same screen?

Comment: Thank you sir. I have problem second view  not work, I want a duplicate image on the same screen.

Comment: Hey @JohnPod i had a same Problem. now i am developing a camera App and i used Surfaceview for My App.also i want to use more Camera Preview on a single activity. that is why i need solution of this Question I Already asked this Question Here,Please Check :- stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/… ..please tell me if anyone know about that.PLEASE. HELP ME Guys..):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in a layout needs to have a unique id.  you have identified both screen elements as `@+id/surfaceView`.  Try making them both unique.  See modified layout file below - also don't forget to update your source code to populate both screen elements.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="th.in.cybernoi.cardboardview.MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add code to your program to reference both SurfaceView objects.  You just duplicate the code you already have.  You should also check the rest of your program for other references to your SurfaceView object that need to be updated.

```
            surfaceViewLeft = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewLeft);
        surfaceHolderLeft = surfaceViewLeft.getHolder();

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        surfaceHolderLeft.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolderLeft.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        surfaceViewRight = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewRight);
        surfaceHolderRight = surfaceViewRight.getHolder();

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        surfaceHolderRight.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        surfaceHolderRight.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

The key is to realize that although your left and right views are the same type of object (they are both `SurfaceViews`) they *are completely unaware of each other*.  If you want something to happen to one view, you must write code that works explicitly on that view.  If you also want it to happen in the other view, you must write code that works explicitly on the other view.  This is an example of having two *instances* of the same *object.*

**UPDATE**:  Upon further digging, I see that the above changes are neccesary but not sufficient.  your call to `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolderLeft);` only allows a single preview `SurfaceView` to be defined, so you can't preview on two surfaces using this method.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, I recommend creating a bitmap of the preview image (which can be obtained in a callback called `onPreviewFrame()`, which is similar to your `onPictureTaken() callback.  The bitmap data will be passed in through the first parameter)  Then get a`Canvas`for each Surface view (by calling`SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()`, and then draw the bitmap you saved onto each Canvas by calling`Canvas.drawBitmap()`.  This should draw the original image onto each surface view.

Since you will be drawing to each surfaceView directly, you should get rid of the line that sets one of the surfaceViews as a preview so that you are competing with the camera for access to draw there.  get rid of the line `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolderLeft);` and instead write `camera.setPreviewCallback(yourcallbackgoeshere);`

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I tried fix it form recommend you. 
- I changed serfaceViewLeft form serfaceView.
- I changed surfaceHolderLeft form  surfaceHolder.
- I add serfaceViewRight and surfaceHolderRight.
- I fix .xml file.
But 'surfaceViewRight' not work!. 
Can you help me please? Thank you so much sir.

Comment: post your new code.  I can't update your entire project for you.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I will try to do it .

Comment: @JohnPod:  I hope it helps.  The accepted way to thank someone for taking the time and effort to help you with your question is to "upvote" their answer and to "accept" their answer.  I would appreciate if you do so.  If you need help, I can show you how. Or, go read the entire [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page (which will also earn the `Informed` badge for you!)

Comment: Thank you so much , Today I do suggestion form you.  I post new code it has a problem again.

Comment: @JohnPod:  1)  you haven't implemented what I suggested.  I see nothing in your code regarding Canvas objects or bitmaps.  2)  It appears to me that you copied an example off the Internet and attempted to modify it without understanding it.  I cannot help you (no one can) further if you do not understand what you are starting with.   Research the classes used in the example, read the web page the example came from, and THEN you will be ready to start modifying code.  SO is a place to help those who themselves, not a place to get others to write your programs for you.

Comment: I so apologize,Thank you for help from you, I trying it again. :)

Comment: No need to apologize...the advice is given not from a position of anger or frustration, but rather to teach.  Even if SO manages to write your code for you, you will not succeed in making an app if you do not understand how it works.  I recommend Udacity.com for some excellent programming tutorials.

Comment: I really appreciate that recommend me sir. : )

Comment: @rothloup Can you please help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743702/creating-image-capturing-feature-similar-to-cam-scanner-app

Comment: in this thread there is also another SO thread with one more issue while trying something similar

Answer (score 0):

I successfully implemented cloned preview from single camera. Refer to code snippet below.

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback cbPreview = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
        int pf = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat();
        if (pf == ImageFormat.NV21)
            bmp = decodeNV21(bytes, camera);
        else
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        MainActivity.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        MainActivity.mImageView.postInvalidate();
    }
};

private Bitmap decodeNV21(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    Bitmap retimage = null;

    int w = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
    int h = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;

    //Get the YUV image
    YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(data, camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat(), w, h, null);

    //Convert Yuv to Jpeg
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, out_stream);

    //Convert Yuv to jpeg
    retimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(out_stream.toByteArray(), 0, out_stream.size());

    return retimage;
}
```